# Returning a value from the child process to its parent in C created with fork()

Tags: c, concurrency, fork

Learning about forking with C.

I can spawn a child process with `fork()` alright. Suppose that it performs some calculation. When the calculation is done, I'd like it to die and return the result (some `int`) to the parent. How can this be done?

Normally I'd post code of my progress, but that's literally it:

```
int main () {
    pid_t  pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // I'm a child!
        int calculation = 10 + 10;
        // <----- Return 20 to the parent?
    }else{
        // I am the parent, and I am waiting to receive a 20
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: There are various ways, you can google `IPC`(inter-process communication).

Comment: To be picky, `fork` is not standardized in C but in POSIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, because [`exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) gives only an exit code (which conventionally should be `EXIT_SUCCESS`  on success, and has only 7 bits). And the exit code is the only thing that a process returns (see [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), which you should always call to avoid [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)).

You could have parent and child process use some shared memory and semaphores (see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)), but this is complex, so is inappropriate for your case.

The simplest -and probably fastest- way is just to use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s (to be set up *before* `fork`) and have the child process print on its *stdout* to the pipe and the parent process read on the pipe. See [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and also [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

You might want to `fork` *several* (at most a dozen on a desktop) processes in parallel. Then you'll need to multiplex their pipes inputs. For that, have some event loop and use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) in the parent process for the multiplexing.

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Besides pipe and fork, the simplest method is to use popen() and read the childs response on stdout as FILE stream.

You dont have to deal with fork at all. (Though indeed, popen is implemented on top of fork and pipe and dup2).

pclose() can be used to check the exit status of child.

Comment: `pclose` *should* be used with `popen` (since it calls `waitpid`).

Comment: My point is pclose _can_ be used to check exit status though more often it is only used in a fire and forget fashion.

Comment: BTW, `popen` is not appropriate in this particular case: the OP is forking but is not `exec`-ing some other program.

Comment: I agree. I should have read the question clearer. I think you've said it well enough in your answer already.